# My custom block doesn't show up in the block library

Tags: blocks, 9

I'm writing a custom Drupal 8 module that creates a block.  On my local sites, I can enable this module and add this block to whatever region I'd like, and the block shows the correct contents.  However, after I deploy this same code to my live sites (same Drupal version) and enable the module, the block never shows up in the block library (/admin/structure/block/list/[theme]).

I've tried simplifying the module name (in case my module name "Simple TOC Block" was breaking anything), clearing cache, simplifying the block contents, and adding a dependency to drupal:block, but nothing has gotten this block to show up in the library.

This is my block code, which is under /Plugin/block/SimpleTOCBlock.php.

```php
namespace Drupal\simple_toc_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'SimpleTOCBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "simple_toc_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Simple TOC Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Simple TOC Block"),
 * )
 */
class SimpleTOCBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $unique_id = uniqid();
    $build = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<span id="simple-toc-block-' . $unique_id . '" class="simple-toc-block-placeholder" data-uniqueid="' . $unique_id . '"></span>',
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => ['simple_toc_block/simple_toc_block'],
      ],
      '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => ['url'],
      ],
    ];

    return $build;
  }

}
```

This issue sounds identical to [My custom block doesn't show up in the block library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341113/my-custom-block-in-drupal-8-does-not-show-up-in-block-layout) on Stack Overflow, but the responses there didn't help.

Comment: `/Plugin/block` should be `/Plugin/Block` in the folder name. You're probably working on a case-insensitive file system locally and deploying to a case-sensitive one

Comment: Thank you, @Clive!  That was EXACTLY the issue.